# jGit CheckoutCommand results in a strange behaviour

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to use `CheckoutCommand` the following way:

```java
Git git = new Git(repository);
CheckoutCommand checkoutCommand = git.checkout();       
checkoutCommand.setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM);
checkoutCommand.setStartPoint("origin/" + branchName);
checkoutCommand.setCreateBranch(true);
checkoutCommand.setForce(true);

checkoutCommand.call();
```

I tried using `SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK` as well but it still failed.

This results in a strange behaviour:
the repository contents are deleted and instead a clone from each remote branch is created.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the name of the branch to create, which should result in an exception on `call()` (is it possible that you are swallowing that?). Add a call like this:

```
 checkoutCommand.setName(branchName);
```

See the [documentation of CheckoutCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.html) (the above is mentioned [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CheckoutCommand.html#setCreateBranch%28boolean%29)).

Also note that these calls can be chained, so you could also write it like this:

```
git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName(branchName) // ...
```